# dyld[xxxxx]: missing symbol called after update to ruby 3.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am responsible for a ruby on rails app. I updated ruby to version 3.1.4 from 2.7.8.
After the update to 3.1.4 when I run any rails command i get: dyld[five_numbers]: missing symbol called. No backtrace nothing just that line.

When I revert back to ruby 2.7.8 everything works again as it should. I have other rails apps on my system and there I don't have this problem. I have no clue what to do where to search, how to turn up log level/backtrace for dyld.

The gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.1.4'

gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'rubylight'

gem 'geometry'
gem 'cmath'
gem 'mathn'
#gem 'attachment_fu', git: "ssh://git@itgit.mdc-berlin.net/it/attachment_fu.git"
#gem 'attachment_fu', git: "https://github.com/ugifractal/attachment_fu.git", branch: "rails5.2"
#gem 'pothoven-attachment_fu'

gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'validatable'
gem 'active_directory', git: "https://github.com/ajrkerr/active_directory.git"
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.3'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '6.1.7.4'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I found the reason for the error by getting the project to run on a colleague's Ubuntu machine. There the error message was:

```
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.4/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: /home/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@blackboard_314_6173/gems/mathn-0.1.0/lib/mathn/rational.so: undefined symbol: nurat_canonicalization
```

Mathn is a deprecated ruby library obviously not compatible with ruby 3.x In the project gem 'mathn' together with gem 'geometry' and
gem 'cmath' are needed for attachment_fu which we use for handling a attachments.attachment_fu was agem and we run it in the project from the lib folder. Yes it is legacy code. Very old.
I am now going to substitute it by using ActiveStorage.

So the real question is why the heck is macOS masking that ruby error? Is there any way to avoid it in the future in case it happens again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76447424/2483313

Comment: No I tried this before I posted my question.

Comment: How did you update your ruby? Are you using a version tool like asdf/rbenv/rvm? Or did you just update your system ruby?

Comment: I use rvm and an .rvmrc file for every rails project I am responsible for.